Micro Frontend Using Module Federation in Webpack 5
We are working on a project there webpack v4 was used then we upgraded to webpack v5 (5.93.0) and some loaders are also upgraded. Then We want to connect one of our remote app which is in React (18.3.0) and the parent app is in React 16.8.0 .
Please help me thank you..
this is configuration modulefederation for parent app
https://i.sstatic.net/oJ17sYQA.png
this is the configuration modulefederation for remote app
This is the component where i am dynamically importing the exposed app from that remote app in parent app
The Error I am facing that
